# What is the correct way to use linecontainsregexp in Ant build?

Tags: java, ant, build, build-process, build-automation

Wnen I added

```
<linecontainsregexp negate="true">
                 <regexp pattern="src=&quot;http://*"/>
            </linecontainsregexp>
```

inside `<replaceregexp>` task, I am getting error
`replaceregexp doesn't support the nested "linecontainsregexp" element.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<linecontainsregexp>` is only valid inside `<filterchain>`.  In turn, `<filterchain>`s is not supported by task `<replaceregexp>`.    are only supported by tasks

`<replaceregexp>` is usually applied after copying files.  `<filterchain>`s are applied **while** copies are performed.

Basically, you have 2 alternatives:

1. Modify your `<replaceregexp>` task with a more sophisticated regular expression that only matches what you want, probably resorting to lookarounds.
2. Add a `<filterchain>` to the `<copy>` or `<move>` task that you are using to copy these files from your source management system.  Include filter `<tokenfilter>`, most probably with a child `<filetokenizer/>`, and children `<containsregex>` and `<replaceregex>` as needed.  This is much more flexible.  There are a couple dozen filters and tokenizers to choose from.

Comment: using the replaceregexp, I am trying to append a parameter to all script tags in my jsps. But I need this to be done only to internal scripts. ie, if the src refers to an outside script like `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com">` the operation is not needed. I thought that can be done by adding  `<linecontainsregexp negate="true">` and adding a regex to match src with "http://...." So that cannot be done rt?

Comment: @user1266172  Changed my answer accordingly.  If you give more cases of internal and external scripts (or a RegExp to distinguish), as well as the substitution, I could help more if you want.

Comment: Thank you @Mario Rossi. I chose the first option, changed the regular epression to suit my need.

Comment: @user1266172  Very glad to hear that :-)